# Seamos pacientes con los votos cuando una pregunta está en inglés

Tags: discusión, votos, idiomas, código-de-conducta

Cuando una pregunta está en inglés, es obvio que el usuario no sabe que no tiene cabida aquí (o como en algún caso, se piensa que lo está publicando en la versión inglesa de Stack Overflow jeje).

Lo que hay que hacer es votar para cerrar esa pregunta e informar al usuario de que tiene que traducirla.

Si uno entiende el inglés y vota positivo/negativo en función del contenido de la pregunta, perfecto.

Pero si votas negativo solo porque la pregunta está en inglés, espera un poco por favor.

La pregunta una vez traducida puede ser perfectamente válida, interesante, de calidad... y entre que votaste negativo y se traduce pasa tanto tiempo que no recuerdas quitar tu voto negativo. Eso repercute en la valoración de la pregunta cuando el idioma ya no es una variable a tener en cuenta.

Recomendaría votar negativo si la pregunta está **cerrada** (que no en espera)  ya que se le ha notificado al usuario que su pregunta ha de ser traducida, se ha cerrado y han pasado 5 días sin cambios ... Ahí ese voto negativo es importante porque tras varios días sin noticias del autor, esa pregunta puede estar abandonada para su olvido y los votos negativos ayudarán a su borrado.

¿Qué opinan?

Comment: Totalmente de acuerdo, me parece la mejor forma de actuar esperar antes de votar negativo si la razón es el idioma. Tal vez podría aplicarse este criterio a otros casos pero el del idioma en concreto es bastante evidente que se trata de un error.

Comment: O sea que cuando uno se registra en SOes y hace una pregunta por primera vez ¿no hay ningún indicio que este sitio está en español?  ¿Cuando uno hace una pregunta por primera vez el botón de "Formular una pregunta" se llama "Ask question"? La verdad ya no me acuerdo de los textos en mi primera pregunta... a lo mejor a partir de la segunda ya aparecen en español. Porque a lo mejor es más fácil poner un letrero grandote que diga "Escriba tu pregunta en español".

Comment: @toledano no se cuanto tiempo pasas en la cola de revisión pero hay muchas en inglés y **hoy** mismo una de un usuario que se equivocó con el sitio inglés...y gente que se viene al Chat español sin hablar ni papa equivocandose

Comment: Pues yo pensaba que me pasaba mucho tiempo, por lo menos durante mis horas de trabajo y claro que he visto preguntas en inglés, pero no creo que veo dos o tres al día. No me parecen muchas, pero supongo que eso se debe a mi sistema de referencia... por cierto que en el chat, solo una vez he visto a alguien cuya lengua nativa era el inglés y en el sitio a un solo usuario que escribía en portuñol.

Comment: @toledano hombre, para lo dificil que es despistarse con eso que dices de "Ask a question/Formular una pregunta"  3 al dia me parecen bastantes xD

Comment: No puedo estar más de acuerdo. Y aunque acabo de leer este tema, he actuado así por instinto y sentido común. Pero todavía ahora, meses después de su publicación, hay usuarios votando negativo a preguntas en inglés antes incluso de que se notifique a los usuarios, habría que empezar a compartir el enlace a esta publicación para ir informando a los rezagados.

Comment: @Muriano, si yo tambien lo consideraba *sentido comun* pero está claro que "el sentido comun es el menos comun de los sentidos" y por eso hice este post. Probablemente vieras el enlace que puse en una pregunta de hoy en inglés. Gracias por tu comentario .Un saludo

Answer (score 1):

Totalmente de acuerdo.

Se debería de votar positivo o negativo dependiendo del contenido de la pregunta, no del idioma en la que esté escrita.

Un usuario puede tener una equivocación ya que, a fin de cuentas, el nombre es el mismo y sólo cambia la extensión.

Sin embargo, esto no quiere decir que no se deba cerrar la pregunta. Esta se debe de cerrar y si el usuario rectifica se debe reabrir (por supuesto, si la calidad de la pregunta lo requiere).

Yo establecería un plazo máximo para la pregunta como dices de 5 días. El OP tiene plazo suficiente para poder traducirla y en caso de que la pregunta no haya sido traducida significa que el OP no tiene interés en la pregunta o se ha buscado otras alternativas (seguramente se habrá ido a Stackoverflow en inglés si no entiende el español, como es normal). En ese caso, si que votaría la pregunta negativa independientemente del contenido para poder proceder a su eliminación.

Comment: lo que dices de reabrir si tiene calidad suficiente tambien lo he pensado. A veces traducen una pregunta que va a ser cerrada. pero yo la abro igual. porque el motivo de cierre tras la traduccion puede ser distinto al original.

Comment: @lois6b En realidad no creo que se deba reabrir simplemente para volverla a cerrar por otro motivo. Si el OP quiere que la pregunta se reabra tendrá que esforzarse para ello y hacer una pregunta correcta.

Comment: yo discrepo. el usuario tiene el feedback de que esa pregunta no tiene relacion con el sitio por estar en inglés. no sabe si su contenido está mal (muy amplia, no está claro, ...). eso toca decidirlo una vez que esté en español.

Comment: @lois6b Tienes razón, para el OP puede quedar un poco contradictorio.

Answer (score 1):

## Respuesta corta

Sí, seamos pacientes como lo haríamos con cualquier publicación.

## Explicación

De acuerdo a la respuesta a [¿Podríamos tener un pequeño detector de publicaciones en inglés que notificara a los autores?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2043/65) ya contamos con un detector de publicaciones en inglés, además el sitio ya cuenta con varios meses de haberse graduado y con prácticamente todos los elementos de la interface en español.

Considerando lo anterior considero que hoy día no deberíamos ser particularmente pacientes con las preguntas en idiomas diferentes al español.

Comment: Entiendo tu punto pero aun con la interfaz en español , hay muchos casos aun de despistes diarios. Gracias por la respuesta

Answer (score -1):

No se debe votar solo por no entender el idioma, debería restringirse eso, debe votar cuando entienda de que versa la pregunta y si tiene relacion con algunos de sus campos de acción

Comment: Va mas allá de no entender el idioma, este es un sitio de preguntas y respuestas en español y cuando una pregunta sale del contexto del sitio es cuando se debe actuar (talvés no votando negativo pero depende mucho de la pregunta/respuesta). Recuerda que es un sitio moderado por los usuarios y existe la libertad de votar a favor o en contra. Por cierto, ¿a qué te refieres con "*sus campos de acción*"? Es preferible responder directamente con ejemplos y evitar caer en especulación

Comment: Claro todo es tan subjetivo como tu opinion, si pretendes ser moderador a partir de estos comentarios no lo creo. El idioma si es un factor por algo el sitio está en español, como dije antes no por eso se debe dar un voto negativo. El campo de acción se refiere por ejemlo a que programas en C#, SQL for SQL Server.,  Yo lo que se es R,,,y vas a estar condiconado a dar un voto negativo a una pregunta que a lo mejor para el lenguaje de R tiene sus complicaciones pero para C#, puede ser un pavada. A eso me refería

Comment: No entiendo lo que quieres decir. No se trata de no entender el idioma sino de que este *stack* es exclusivamnte en español y las preguntas en otros idiomas no tienen cabida,si no se traducen se cierran. La gente puede votar negativo porque una pregunta en inglés (que yo sepa no se ha dado el caso de otros idiomas) está fuera de lugar en este sitio aunque como se ha comentado es preferible esperar un poco antes de votar en estos caso, aun así cada uno vota según su propio criterio.