# No hay motivo de cierre para respuestas en inglés

Tags: soporte, respuesta, idiomas, reportes

Al reportar respuestas, ¿podría existir un motivo de cierre para las escritas en inglés?

Se podría solicitar por medio de esta opción:

> se necesita la intervención de un moderador

Pero sería más correcto que existiera la opción de cierre porque la pregunta está en inglés.

Acabo de ver [una respuesta en inglés](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/162959/83), cuya imagen es:

> [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Las respuestas no se cierran (: Por otro lado no debería combinarse [meta-tag:característica-nueva] con otras etiquetas obligatorias pues cambian el significado de los votos.Cuando se usa [meta-tag:característica-nueva] los votos significan *de acuerdo* / *desacuerdo* mientras que en las otras etiquetas se vota por *utilidad* / *claridad*

Comment: No sabia eso :( bueno y para esta pregunta entonces que se podra editar entonces?  voy agregar la etiiqueta

Comment: @Rubén puedo agregar a la información de la etiqueta el significado de los votos

Comment: Si es pregunta,  no recuerdo a partir de qué nivel de rep es posible sugerir ediciones de etiqueta. Para aprobarlos se requiren 5 mil.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Respuesta corta

No aplica votar para cerrar las respuestas, lo que aplica en estos casos es votar negativo con opción a dejar un comentario explicando el motivo.

## Explicación

Las respuestas se pueden reportar pero no se cierran.

No recuerdo haber visto otras respuestas en inglés. Si esto ocurre rara vez no tiene sentido tener un tipo de reporte para esto.

Tampoco veo sentido reportar como "Se requiere intervención de un moderador" sólo por el hecho de estar en inglés, pero bueno a esperar que ellos, los moderadores ♦ comenten al respecto.

Aunque suene obvio, tal vez valdría la pena incluir en [¿Cómo escribo una buena respuesta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) que debe hacerse en español.

Cabe agregar que contamos con un detector de publicaciones en inglés que le muestra al autor un aviso antes de hacer la publicación.

## Referencias

- [Privilegio > Reportar publicaciones](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts)
- [¿Qué hago si veo a alguien haciendo algo malo?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/flagging)
- [¿Podríamos tener un pequeño detector de publicaciones en inglés que notificara a los autores?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2043/65)

Comment: No estoy de acuerdo con votar negativo: la respuesta puede ser buenísima y utilísima. En todo caso, reportar y comentar.

Comment: @fedorqui al igual que [Seamos pacientes con los votos cuando una pregunta está en inglés](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1092/15855)

Comment: @fedorqui también si uno entiende ingles y ve la pregunta muy interesante puede traducirla, aunque luego las respuestas vendrían en español y tal vez el OP no las entienda

Comment: @the-breaker y por eso **no** debemos traducir las preguntas en inglés. No solo porque puede no entender el español si no porque aunque lo entienda, su intención no era esa (hay un motivo para rechazar ediciones por ir en contra de la intención original del autor). Si tras comunicarselo quiere traducirla, estupendo. Si no, podemos o migrarla al sitio en inglés si tiene calidad suficiente o él mismo preguntarlo allÍ. Un saludo