# ¿Por que no se eliminan inmediatamente las preguntas malas?

Tags: discusión, preguntas, eliminación-de-preguntas

Hoy pasó algo que para mi fue bastante curioso, primero un usuario hace esta [Pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/271864/cantidad-de-canciones-en-las-playlists) pensando que somos desarrolladores de Spotify la cual es rápidamente puesta **en espera**, es una pregunta que obviamente es imposible de reabrir ya que no es un problema propio de programación que podamos resolver los usuarios de StackOverflow ¿Vale la pena colocarla en espera? Para mi NO!.

Horas más tarde alguien sube una pregunta donde decía que estaba buscando un desarrollador FullStack Junior para realizar un proyecto, dicha pregunta fue inmediatamente **eliminada** del sitio.

Entonces mi pregunta es ¿por que eliminaron del sitio la pregunta del segundo caso y no la del primer caso que sabemos no puede tener ningún tipo de mejora? ¿No sería bueno eliminar todas las preguntas que no aportan absolutamente nada al sitio?

Comment: Que alguien se equivoque en una pregunta, no es lo mismo a que alguien haga SPAM de algo definitivamente prohibido en el sitio.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Borré la pregunta en la que se buscaban desarrolladores en cuanto la vi porque no se ajustaba a las normas del sitio. No había manera de salvarla por ningún lado.

Sobre la pregunta de Spotify, esa publicación quizás podría salvarse si el usuario la cambia. Por ejemplo, aunque no creo que sea el caso, si el usuario se está refiriendo a la API de Spotify y añade nueva información sobre lo que está intentando hacer: ¿está usando la API? ¿qué versión? ¿es un programa propio? ¿qué problemas concretos está teniendo?

Aunque, lo dicho, creo que igual se refiere a la app de android y no a un proyecto propio, en cuyo caso la pregunta permanecerá cerrada y acabará eliminada automáticamente por el sistema.

Comment: Me parece más preocupante el +1 que tiene. No es la primera pregunta que obviamente no se ajusta al formato del sitio y tiene votos positivos, parece que alguien se divierte dándole positivos a estas preguntas.

Comment: el +1 es mio debido [este planteamiento en el meta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1092/seamos-pacientes-con-los-votos-cuando-una-pregunta-est%C3%A1-en-ingl%C3%A9s)  algunas de esas preguntas mal formuladas se vuelven a abrir y los que marcaron -1 a la pregunta no  aparece, conclusion el usuario se llena de puntos negativos editando su pregunta, si esta mal que debemos hacer para evitar la lluvia de -1 a usuarios nuevos

Comment: Et tu @JackNavaRow? :P

Comment: si , esta vez hablamos de la misma pregunta la de spotify

Comment: @JackNavaRow ¿estás diciendo que le diste +1 a [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/271864/83)? No estaba en inglés. Por lo demás, recordemos [votar por contenido](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1935/83), no por cualquier otra cosa (compensar otros votos, quién es, hoy hace sol o el Barça ganó la Champions :P)

Comment: @fedorqui voto positivo a usuarios generalmente nuevos que hacen preguntas debiles y que la comunidad los llena de -1  para evitar si reabren la pregunta por lo menos tenga 0 de puntuacion, lo mejor sera que haga una pregunta en el meta para explicarme mejor

Comment: @JackNavaRow quizás una publicación sería buena. Comprendo tu razonamiento, pero esa forma de votar puede tener consecuencias negativas para el sitio: preguntas malas con votos positivos pueden no acabar eliminadas automáticamente, los usuarios pueden sentirse reivindicados ("recibí 2 negativos, pero también 1 positivo; así que voy a seguir haciendo lo mismo"), un voto positivo da más puntos de los que quita uno negativo por lo que se está premiando una mala publicación (hacen falta 3 negativos en preguntas y 5 en respuestas)...

Comment: excelente explicacion!! gracias, de igual forma en respuesta no lo hago, las reporto, en caso de las preguntas las marco como cerrada pero en algunas ocasiones tiene -10(10 usuarios que pudieron reportar la pregunta) y no esta cerrada lo ideal es que no le den -1 y solo marquen para cerrar o el contenido de verdad sea ofensivo, pero creo que es otra pregunta al meta

Answer (score 4):

Según lo descrito las dos publicaciones son de naturaleza distinta, mientras que una es una "pregunta" la otra es SPAM.

Se tiene tolerancia para las "preguntas" que no cumplan con los lineamientos del sitio tanto porque se podrían corregir así como también se pueden usar para aclararle al autor y otros usuarios los motivos de haberla puesto en espera / cierre así como dar orientación sobre las correcciones a realizar y sobre cómo preguntar en este sitio.

Viendo la publicación sobre Spotify, se podría argumentar que más que una pregunta es una queja dirigida a los desarrolladores de dicho servicio, sin embargo, me parece que aún así es válido seguir el proceso descrito.

No se tiene tolerancia al Spam porque es perjudicial para el sitio ya que distrae, ocupa recursos entre otros perjuicios.

Aún si un moderador diamantado no la borra de forma inmediata, en mi opinión terminaría siendo borrada rápidamente por reportes de spam.